# MYSQL TRIGGER subquery update

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm new working with my SQL, and I develop a trigger in SQLSERVER that is running perfect, now I'm trying to convert it, to use in Mysql, but doesn't work and I don't know what to do.

here's the code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_test AFTER UPDATE ON  YET FOR EACH ROW

INSERT INTO CONTROLETRIGGER(idAluno, idNivel)
values(NEW.IdAluno, NEW.idNivel);


UPDATE HistoricoNivel AS E
join(
select max(h.idNivel) Nivel, h.idAluno
from HistoricoNivel h
join CONTROLETRIGGER v on h.idaluno = v.idaluno
WHERE h.dtFim is null
group by h.idAluno
)X on E.idAluno = X.idAluno and E.idNivel= X.Nivel
join CONTROLETRIGGER vi on vi.idaluno = E.idAluno
set E.dtFim = case when X.idnivel <> vi.idNivel then CURRENT_DATE() else null end
```

Please, what i'm doing wrong ?

Tks.

Comment: What is not working? Is it not compiling? Not giving the desired effect? ...? Also, you may want to show the actual trigger, not just the queries in it (if that is what the update is...?)

Comment: it's not compiling, this is the code of my trigger.

Comment: Well, if you want a trigger `CREATE TRIGGER` is definitely missing...

Comment: hahahaha, i know this @Joachim, I thought wasn't necessary put it here.

Answer (score 0):

The `X` subquery does not have a field called `idnivel`, so the case statement will not compile.

I assume what you want here is `nivel`, which would make the full trigger;

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_test AFTER UPDATE ON  YET FOR EACH ROW
 INSERT INTO CONTROLETRIGGER(idAluno, idNivel) VALUES (NEW.IdAluno, NEW.idNivel);
 UPDATE HistoricoNivel AS E
 JOIN(
  SELECT MAX(h.idNivel) Nivel, h.idAluno
  FROM HistoricoNivel h
  JOIN CONTROLETRIGGER v ON h.idaluno = v.idaluno
  WHERE h.dtFim IS NULL
  GROUP BY h.idAluno
 ) X 
 ON E.idAluno = X.idAluno AND E.idNivel= X.Nivel
 JOIN CONTROLETRIGGER vi ON vi.idaluno = E.idAluno
 SET E.dtFim = CASE WHEN X.nivel <> vi.idNivel THEN CURRENT_DATE() ELSE NULL END
//
```

[See it compile here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3ab962/1).

Comment: Still not running. I'm using phpmyadmin. Only the one statment has been created. When i let both i'm getting a error at the line 2. Can be a problem of phpmyadmin ?

Comment: @FpontoDesenv You need to change the delimiter when adding it so that it does not think the proc ends at the first `;`. Note that the SQLfiddle is changed to `//` instead of `;`. Not sure how to do it in PHPmyadmin, but in the normal MySQL command prompt, you'd issue `delimiter //` before adding the proc, and `delimiter ;` to go back again after adding it.

Comment: Thank you, Joachim. I make this go using stored procedures.